# Java using obj.threadobj.join throws error

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, compiler-errors

I want the child thread to finish before the main thread continues its operation.

After starting the thread, I am calling `join`, which I thought would finish the child thread before continuing with the main thread but throws some I could not understand why it throws the error.

Following is my code:

```
class FirstThread implements Runnable{
    Thread t;
    String threadname;
    FirstThread(String name){
        threadname = name;
        t = new Thread(this,threadname);
        System.out.println(name+" Starting");
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){
                System.out.println(threadname+" : "+ i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ e);
        }
    }

}

public class ThreadJoin {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Starting child Thread");
        FirstThread ft = new FirstThread("new thread");
        ft.t.join();
        try{
            for(int i =0; i < 5; i++){
                System.out.println("Main : "+i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Exception : "+ e);
        }

    }

}
```

I have the following code

```
    FirstThread ft = new FirstThread("new thread");
    ft.t.join();
```

to create a new thread and make it finish first by using `ft.t.join`.

but it throws the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      Unhandled exception type InterruptedException
>
> at ThreadJoin.main(ThreadJoin.java:29)

line number 29

ft.t.join();

If I remove the above line it works fine.

Comment: Have you considered fixing your compilation errors *before* attempting to execute your program?

Comment: I know why this question deserves a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Thread#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) declared that it throws an `InterruptedException`. You must handle it somehow - either allow the caller to throw it too, or catch it. Just move the offending line inside the `catch` block and you should be fine:

```
try {
    ft.t.join(); // Here!
    for (int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Main : "+i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
} catch(InterruptedException e){
    System.out.println("Exception : "+ e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much